# how to change gridview cell color based on cell item in DevExpress

Tags: c#, datagridview, devexpress, aspxgridview

My ASPxGridView is loading massive data from the Database. Every time there is a new data load on the grid, I would each Cellstyle color to Display the BackColor according to resource from Database.

I will try to clarify I want to achieve here below:

**This is what I tried.** It's Working but all the rest of the rows continue to be System.Drawing.Color.Red.That I don't want to see.

```
protected void ASPxGridViewTicketList_CustomUnboundColumnData(object sender, DevExpress.Web.ASPxGridViewColumnDataEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Column.Caption == "Status")
        {

            Object is_priority = e.GetListSourceFieldValue("ispriority");

            if (is_priority.ToString() == "1")
            {
                 e.Column.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;

            }
            else
            {
                e.Column.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.AliceBlue;

            }


        }

    }
```

Do you have a solution for that? Thank you!

Here is an Illustration:

1. I would like to stop the cooling of the color over and over while there is a condition state that if == 1 then RED else White. In this illustration, There is only **1 row that must be RED** and the others to stay white. But it's not working.

[image]

Comment: Please, paste the screenshot of the actual grid and mark the new rows which you want to have displayed with different background color.

Comment: Ok, I will add it to my quetion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are trying to change the BackColor in the wrong place. CustomUnboundColumnData is more data related event. When you call

```
e.Column.CellStyle.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
```

during CustomUnboundColumnData it sets back color for the whole column, i.e. all Status cells.

To set the background color for a specific unbound cell, you need to handle a cell-specific 'paint' event like [HtmlDataCellPrepared](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_HtmlDataCellPreparedtopic) or row-specific event like [HtmlRowCreated](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#AspNet/DevExpressWebASPxGridView_HtmlRowCreatedtopic).

For HtmlDataCellPrepared example see this post: https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/Q308988 . The example should be straightforward. You check the needed column against e.DataColumn.FieldName and the needed column value in e.CellValue, then you can determine if to paint the row red or not.

I trust you'll be able to add handlers to the mentioned events yourself.

HTH

Comment: Thanks for your clear answer, I will try it now thanks.

Comment: Thank you Very much, I spent Time to Look to the Correct answer. By your Lead @andrews, I manage to get the accurate answer. I should make use of `protected void ASPxGridViewTicket_HtmlDataCellPrepared(object sender, ASPxGridViewTableDataCellEventArgs e)` Method to get the color right.

Comment: @MichealP. you're welcome! I'm glad you get it resolved ;).